# Google app engine tutorial, can't get Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ssl, backend, sha1

I am following the guide at: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/ using Android Studio.

I have followed the tutorial from beginning up to 'Download and set up sample app'.

I am trying to create the Android client ID, but to do this I need a 'Signing certificate fingerprint (SHA1)'.

I am running the following in a terminal to obtain said fingerprint:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v | openssl sha1`

However it returns one line after I enter the debug password 'android':

`(stdin)= 7a509420fd8b59047b7e4d`....... (more characters)

which looks nothing like the example SHA1 fingerprint given.

Since there is no error message I have no idea how to proceed; how should I obtain the fingerprint if this script doesn't work?

I am completely new to App Engine, and backends in general, so please assume no knowledge in any answers!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a different command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

despite the original command being on the google guide

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this, if you use eclipse:

Go to window->Preferences->Choose Android from side menu-> Build

There you will find the SHA1 fingerprint.

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant to switch from Android Studio just for this, as it is the supported IDE. There must be a problem that needs addressing here, as the script isn't giving me what is expected!